# How can I fix 'undefined' output from my function that retrieves cookie values in Electron using Node.js promises?

Tags: node.js, promise, electron

I have this function to get cookies values if cookies exist or false if not, but i get undefined

This is my function :

```
function ifCookieExist(cookieName) {
    session.defaultSession.cookies.get({ name: cookieName })
      .then((cookies) => {
        return cookies[0].value
      }).catch((error) => {
        return false
      })
  }
```

called here :
`console.log(ifCookieExist('actualList'));`

actual result : `undefined`
expected result : **cookies value** or **false**

for info when i use console.log inside function like this :

```
function ifCookieExist(cookieName) {
    session.defaultSession.cookies.get({ name: cookieName })
      .then((cookies) => {
        console.log(cookies[0].value)
      }).catch((error) => {
        return false
      })
  }
```

i got expected result in console

Comment: You never `return` anything from `ifCookieExist` function itself, only from the `then` and `catch` callback functions.